# Create configurable products programatically Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails `` (`m1937`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set`
>   (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELE) ``

Comment: Please add the code you used  to perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

First create simple product and than we can assign it to configurable product.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
try {
$simpleProduct
//    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
//    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
    ->setSku('simple99y') //SKU
    ->setName('test simple product99') //product name
    ->setWeight(4.0000)
    ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
    ->setColor(24)
    ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
    ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
    ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
    ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
    ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
    ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
    ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
    ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
    ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
    ->setDescription('This is a long description')
    ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
    ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
    ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            'qty' => 999 //qty
        )
    )
    ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
    $simpleProduct->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What we need to do now is create a configurable product and assign this simple product to it.

```
$configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');,
try {
$configProduct
//    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setTypeId('configurable') //product type
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
//    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
        ->setSku('configurable96') //SKU
        ->setName('test config product96') //product name
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
        ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
        ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
        ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
        ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
        ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
        ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
        ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
        ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
        ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
        ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
        ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
        ->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            )
        )
        ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)) //assign product to categories
    ;
    /**/
    /** assigning associated product to configurable */
    /**/
    $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(92)); //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
    $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();

    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

    $configurableProductsData = array();
    $configurableProductsData['920'] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'Green', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '92', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => '24', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '21' //value for the pricing
        )
    );
    $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
    $configProduct->save();

    echo 'success';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And that’s it! Your configurable product should be properly set up and visible on the frontend!

Answer (score 0):

this is my code , but it's create duplicate configurable product

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name'))->load();
$productName = array();

foreach($collection as $collection1) {
    $productName[] = $collection1->getName();
}

$getData = array_unique($productName);

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('in'=> $getData));
$productCollection->load();

$newArr = array();
foreach ($productCollection->getData() as $val) {
    $newArr[$val[name]] = $val;    
}
$productUniqeArray = array_values($newArr);

foreach ($productUniqeArray as $productData) {

    /* define attribute code */
    $attributeColorCode = 'color';
    $attributeSizeCode = 'size';


    /* return function to getting the attribute color id */
    $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeColorCode);
    $attribute = $attribute_details->getData();
    $attribute_colorid = $attribute['attribute_id'];

    /* return function to getting the attribute size id */
    $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeSizeCode);
    $attribute = $attribute_details->getData();
    $attribute_sizeid = $attribute['attribute_id'];

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productData['entity_id']);
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($_product);
    echo $_product->getName(); //product name
    $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

            $configProduct
    //->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
    ->setTypeId('configurable') //product type
    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
    ->setSku($_product->getSku()."_config") //SKU
    ->setName($_product->getName()) //product name
    ->setUrlKey($url)->setWeight(1)->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
    ->setTaxClassId(2) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
    ->setNewsFromDate('') //product set as new from
    ->setNewsToDate('') //product set as new to
    ->setPrice($_product->getPrice()) //price in form 11.22
    ->setDescription($_product->getDescription())->setShortDescription($_product->getShortDescription())
    ->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        )
    )

    ->setCategoryIds(array(3)); //assign product to categories

    /* get collection of all simple products gonna assing to configurable products ( I have assigned an attribute value to all simple products to group them and get collection ) */
    $simpleProducts = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addIdFilter(array(2,3))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('color')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('size')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price');

    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

    /* set attributes from which you need to create configurable product */
    $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array($attribute_colorid,$attribute_sizeid));

    $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
    $configurableProductsData = array();

    foreach ($simpleProducts as $simple) {
        $productData = array(
        'label' => $simple->getAttributeText('color'),
        'attribute_id' => $attribute_colorid,
        'value_index' => (int) $simple->getColor(),
        'is_percent' => 0,
        'pricing_value' => $simple->getPrice()
        );

        $configurableProductsData[$simple->getId()] = $productData;
        $configurableAttributesData[0]['values'][] = $productData;

        $productData = array(
        'label' => $simple->getAttributeText('size'),
        'attribute_id' => $attribute_sizeid,
        'value_index' => (int) $simple->getSize(),
        'is_percent' => 0,
        'pricing_value' => $simple->getPrice()
        );

        $configurableProductsData[$simple->getId()] = $productData;
        $configurableAttributesData[1]['values'][] = $productData;
    }

    $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
    $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);

    Mage::log($configurableProductsData, null, 'configurableProductsData.log', true);
    Mage::log($configurableAttributesData, null, 'configurableAttributesData.log', true);

    $configProduct->save();
    $confId = $configProduct->getId();
```